# Refresh div content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to use jQuery to refresh the content of a div, the content of which comes from a script. I tried this:

```
    $("#btn_blue_refresh").click(function(){
    $("#div_captcha").replaceWith("<div id='div_captcha'><script type='text/javascript'>sjcap();</script></div>");
});
```

But instead of replacing the content of the div, it replaces the content of the entire page.  Here is the html:

```
        <form class="form_request" name="form_request1" id="form_request1" action="http://www.myurl.com/referemail" method="post">  
        <div class="request_field" id="request_field_firstname">
            <input class="request_input" type="text" value="Contact Name" name="firstname" id="request_input_firstname" size="35"></input>
        </div>  
        <div class="request_field" id="request_field_lastname">
            <input class="request_input" type="text" value="Business Name" name="lastname" id="request_input_lastname" size="35"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="request_field" id="request_field_phone">
            <input class="request_input" type="text"  value="Phone" name="phone" id="request_input_phone" size="35"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="request_field" id="request_field_email">
            <input class="request_input" type="text" value="Email" name="email" id="request_input_email" size="35"></input>
        </div>
        <div class="request_field" id="request_field_comment">
            <input class="request_input" type="text" value="Comment" name="comment" id="request_input_comment" size="35"></input>
        </div>
        <div id="div_captcha"><script type="text/javascript">sjcap();</script></div>
        <div class="request_btn" id="request_btn_submit">
            <a href="sent.aspx" class="btn_blue" id="btn_blue_send" title="Send Your Request">
Send
            </a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:void();" class="btn_blue" id="btn_blue_refresh" title="Refresh image">
Refresh
            </a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And here is the script with the function that fills in the div:

```
/* Client-side CAPTCHA */
var imgdir = "./images/jscap1/";        // identify directory where captcha images are located
var jfldid = "request_field_captcha";   // identify word field id name
var jfldsz = 12;                        // identify word field size

function sjcap(jfldcls) {
    imgdir = encodeURIComponent(imgdir);
    if (jfldcls == null) {
        jfldcls = "";
    }
    anum = (Math.floor(Math.random()*191))+1;
    imgid = parseInt(anum);
    cword = 
    [
        "60ee0bc62638fccf2d37ac27a634a9e9", "68e2d83709f317938b51e53f7552ed04", "f4c9385f1902f7334b00b9b4ecd164de",
         "df491a4de50739fa9cffdbd4e3f4b4bb", "ef56b0b0ddb93c2885892c06be830c68", "fe4c0f30aa359c41d9f9a5f69c8c4192",
         "cbf4e0b7971051760907c327e975f4e5", "ea9e801b0d806f2398bd0c7fe3f3f0cd", "609a8f6f218fdfe6f955e19f818ec050",
         "cbf4e0b7971051760907c327e975f4e5", "8cb554127837a4002338c10a299289fb", "28f9b1cae5ae23caa8471696342f6f0c",
         "74e04ddb55ce3825f65ebec374ef8f0d", "567904efe9e64d9faf3e41ef402cb568", "7edabf994b76a00cbc60c95af337db8f",
         "639849f6b368019778991b32434354fc", "7edabf994b76a00cbc60c95af337db8f", "dd8fc45d87f91c6f9a9f43a3f355a94a",
         "eb5c1399a871211c7e7ed732d15e3a8b", "8cb554127837a4002338c10a299289fb", "0b8263d341de01f741e4deadfb18f9eb",
         "87fa4eaaf3698e1b1e2caadabbc8ca60", "327a6c4304ad5938eaf0efb6cc3e53dc", "841a2d689ad86bd1611447453c22c6fc",
         "ceb20772e0c9d240c75eb26b0e37abee", "a3e2a6cbf4437e50816a60a64375490e", "bc8fba5b68a7babc05ec51771bf6be21",
         "68934a3e9455fa72420237eb05902327", "c9fab33e9458412c527c3fe8a13ee37d", "2fc01ec765ec0cb3dcc559126de20b30",
         "fcc790c72a86190de1b549d0ddc6f55c", "918b81db5e91d031548b963c93845e5b", "9dfc8dce7280fd49fc6e7bf0436ed325",
         "ea82410c7a9991816b5eeeebe195e20a", "fb81c91eb92d6cb64aeb64c3f37ef2c4", "8d45c85b51b27a04ad7fdfc3f126f9f8",
         "70dda5dfb8053dc6d1c492574bce9bfd", "b9b83bad6bd2b4f7c40109304cf580e1", "981c1e7b3795da18687613fbd66d4954",
         "e170e3a15923188224c1c2bd1477d451", "fb81c91eb92d6cb64aeb64c3f37ef2c4", "cb15e32f389b7af9b285a63ca1044651",
         "632a2406bbcbcd553eec45ac14b40a0a", "e7b95b49658278100801c88833a52522", "6d4db5ff0c117864a02827bad3c361b9",
         "8b373710bcf876edd91f281e50ed58ab", "508c75c8507a2ae5223dfd2faeb98122", "97f014516561ef487ec368d6158eb3f4",
         "23678db5efde9ab46bce8c23a6d91b50", "2d6b0cefb06fd579a62bf56f02b6c2b3", "f1bdf5ed1d7ad7ede4e3809bd35644b0",
         "3ddaeb82fbba964fb3461d4e4f1342eb", "c9507f538a6e79c9bd6229981d6e05a3", "9e925e9341b490bfd3b4c4ca3b0c1ef2",
         "125097a929a62998c06340ea9ef43d77", "a557264a7d6c783f6fb57fb7d0b9d6b0", "eba478647c77836e50de44b323564bdb",
         "45fe7e5529d283851d93b74536e095a0", "56609ab6ba04048adc2cbfafbe745e10", "d938ad5cbe68bec494fbbf4463ad031d",
         "9bbd993d9da7df60b3fd4a4ed721b082", "a6ab62e9da89b20d720c70602624bfc2", "51037a4a37730f52c8732586d3aaa316",
         "7c4f29407893c334a6cb7a87bf045c0d", "3b7770f7743e8f01f0fd807f304a21d0", "29d233ae0b83eff6e5fbd67134b88717",
         "8d45c85b51b27a04ad7fdfc3f126f9f8", "9aa91f81de7610b371dd0e6fe4168b01", "9f27410725ab8cc8854a2769c7a516b8",
         "6ee6a213cb02554a63b1867143572e70", "918b81db5e91d031548b963c93845e5b", "3767b450824877f2b8f284f7a5625440",
         "81513effdf5790b79549208838404407", "7aea2552dfe7eb84b9443b6fc9ba6e01", "d8735f7489c94f42f508d7eb1c249584",
         "fde27e470207e146b29b8906826589cb", "2a2d595e6ed9a0b24f027f2b63b134d6", "99e0d947e01bbc0a507a1127dc2135b1",
         "6758fcdc0da017540d11889c22bb5a6e", "ab1991b4286f7e79720fe0d4011789c8", "28f9b1cae5ae23caa8471696342f6f0c",
         "f5b75010ea8a54b96f8fe7dafac65c18", "2570c919f5ef1d7091f0f66d54dac974", "ada15bd1a5ddf0b790ae1dcfd05a1e70",
         "eb88d7636980738cd0522ea69e212905", "83ab982dd08483187289a75163dc50fe", "8ac20bf5803e6067a65165d9df51a8e7",
         "7c4f29407893c334a6cb7a87bf045c0d", "67942503875c1ae74e4b5b80a0dade01", "d74fdde2944f475adc4a85e349d4ee7b",
         "163ccb6353c3b5f4f03cda0f1c5225ba", "6b1628b016dff46e6fa35684be6acc96", "de1b2a7baf7850243db71c4abd4e5a39",
         "5eda0ea98768e91b815fa6667e4f0178", "23ec24c5ca59000543cee1dfded0cbea", "ea9e801b0d806f2398bd0c7fe3f3f0cd",
         "35393c24384b8862798716628f7bc6f4", "28b26be59c986170c572133aaace31c2", "c2bfd01762cfbe4e34cc97b9769b4238",
         "22811dd94d65037ef86535740b98dec8", "acaa16770db76c1ffb9cee51c3cabfcf", "7516c3b35580b3490248629cff5e498c",
         "b04ab37e571600800864f7a311e2a386", "7e25b972e192b01004b62346ee9975a5", "2764ca9d34e90313978d044f27ae433b",
         "660cb6fe7437d4b40e4a04b706b93f70", "87a429872c7faee7e8bc9268d5bf548e", "31c13f47ad87dd7baa2d558a91e0fbb9",
         "e6ec529ba185279aa0adcf93e645c7cd", "21a361d96e3e13f5f109748c2a9d2434", "85814ce7d88361ec8eb8e07294043bc3",
         "a5fdad9de7faf3a0492812b9cb818d85", "0b8263d341de01f741e4deadfb18f9eb", "0cb47aeb6e5f9323f0969e628c4e59f5",
         "23a58bf9274bedb19375e527a0744fa9", "7e25b972e192b01004b62346ee9975a5", "b9d27d6b3d1915aacd5226b9d702bdbb",
         "6758fcdc0da017540d11889c22bb5a6e", "e2704f30f596dbe4e22d1d443b10e004", "da4f0053a5c13882268852ae2da2e466",
         "1562eb3f6d9c5ac7e159c04a96ff4dfe", "a94aa000f9a94cc51775bd5eac97c926", "1e4483e833025ac10e6184e75cb2d19d",
         "a957a3153eb7126b1c5f8b6aac35de53", "731b886d80d2ea138da54d30f43b2005", "a850c17cba5eb16b0d3d40a106333bd5",
         "7516c3b35580b3490248629cff5e498c", "d508fe45cecaf653904a0e774084bb5c", "18ccf61d533b600bbf5a963359223fe4",
         "f4d3b5a1116ded3facefb8353d0bd5ba", "28b26be59c986170c572133aaace31c2", "d5ca322453f2986b752e58b11af83d96",
         "37b19816109a32106d109e83bbb3c97d", "0423fa423baf1ea8139f6662869faf2f", "8ab8a4dfab57b4618331ffc958ebb4ec",
         "85814ce7d88361ec8eb8e07294043bc3", "273b9ae535de53399c86a9b83148a8ed", "4c9184f37cff01bcdc32dc486ec36961",
         "8ee2027983915ec78acc45027d874316", "1cba77c39b4d0a81024a7aada3655a28", "de1b2a7baf7850243db71c4abd4e5a39",
         "608f0b988db4a96066af7dd8870de96c", "06a224da9e61bee19ec9eef88b95f934", "df55340f75b5da454e1c189d56d7f31b",
         "8c728e685ddde9f7fbbc452155e29639", "2570c919f5ef1d7091f0f66d54dac974", "dce7c4174ce9323904a934a486c41288",
         "573ce5969e9884d49d4fab77b09a306a", "d5ca322453f2986b752e58b11af83d96", "eb88d7636980738cd0522ea69e212905",
         "e7e94d9ef1edaf2c6c55e9966b551295", "762f8817ab6af0971fe330dbf46a359a", "d8a48e3f0e1322d53d401e3dcb3360db",
         "c1940aeeb9693a02e28c52eb85ce261c", "d74fdde2944f475adc4a85e349d4ee7b", "b6a5d96a4e99b63723ab54ddb471baad",
         "6b157916b43b09df5a22f658ccb92b64", "bec670e5a55424d840db8636ecc28828", "4a6cbcd66d270792b89f50771604d093",
         "07202a7e6cbfbabe27abba87989f807e", "d60db28d94d538bbb249dcc7f2273ab1", "123402c04dcfb6625f688f771a5fc05d",
         "cd69b4957f06cd818d7bf3d61980e291", "be1ab1632e4285edc3733b142935c60b", "2bda2998d9b0ee197da142a0447f6725",
         "ba535ef5a9f7b8bc875812bb081286bb", "e9f40e1f1d1658681dad2dac4ae0971e", "eabe04e738cfb621f819e4e8f9489234",
         "aa2d6e4f578eb0cfaba23beef76c2194", "126ac4b07f93bc4f7bed426f5e978c16", "f43dff9a0dc54f0643d0c6d7971635f0",
         "ccaaac957ec37bde4c9993a26a064730", "2feaaf89c21770ea5c21196bc33848dd", "07cf4f8f5d8b76282917320715dda2ad",
         "1ffd9e753c8054cc61456ac7fac1ac89", "6050ce63e4bce6764cb34cac51fb44d1", "327a6c4304ad5938eaf0efb6cc3e53dc",
         "b82c91e2103d0a495c099f0a12f66363", "41d1de28e96dc1cde568d3b068fa17bb", "cad1c068cb62b0681fe4c33d1db1bad6",
         "de1b2a7baf7850243db71c4abd4e5a39", "75e52a0ecfafeda17a34fc60111c1f0b", "fc7e987f23de5bd6562b7c0063cad659",
         "126ac4b07f93bc4f7bed426f5e978c16", "fcc790c72a86190de1b549d0ddc6f55c", "72792fa10d4ca61295194377da0bcc05",
         "821f03288846297c2cf43c34766a38f7", "faec47e96bfb066b7c4b8c502dc3f649", "78b6367af86e03f19809449e2c365ff5",
         "015f28b9df1bdd36427dd976fb73b29d", "755f85c2723bb39381c7379a604160d8"
    ];
    document.write("<div class=\"captcha_img\">&nbsp;<img src=\"" + decodeURIComponent(imgdir) + imgid + ".jpg\" width=\"180px\" height=\"50px\" alt=\"\" ><\/div>");
    document.write("<div class='request_input'><input type=\"text\" name=\"captchaBox\"  value=\"Enter Word Above\" id=\"" + jfldid + "\" name=\"" + jfldid + "\" class=\"" + jfldcls + "\" size=\"" +  jfldsz + "\" onfocus=\"if(this.value=='Enter Word Above') this.value=''\" onblur=\"if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Word Above'; if(this.value==' ') this.value='Enter Word Above';\"><\/div>");
}

function jcap(){
    var uword = hex_md5(document.getElementById(jfldid).value);
    if (uword==cword[anum-1]) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter the word displayed.");
        document.getElementById(jfldid).focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

OK, so I think the way to solve this might be to figure out how to make the document.write() part of the script write to a specific div on the form, instead of overwriting the entire page.  Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Here is the current code:

```
document.write("<div class=\"captcha_img\">&nbsp;<img src=\"" + decodeURIComponent(imgdir) + imgid + ".jpg\" width=\"180px\" height=\"50px\" alt=\"\" ><\/div>");
document.write("<div class='request_input'><input type=\"text\" name=\"captchaBox\"  value=\"Enter Word Above\" id=\"" + jfldid + "\" name=\"" + jfldid + "\" class=\"" + jfldcls + "\" size=\"" +  jfldsz + "\" onfocus=\"if(this.value=='Enter Word Above') this.value=''\" onblur=\"if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Word Above'; if(this.value==' ') this.value='Enter Word Above';\"><\/div>");
```

Comment: And where is `#btn_blue_refresh` ?

Comment: Adeneo: Yes, sorry about that. I edited the post.

Comment: And add a Fiddle too..

Comment: Anupam: The script uses document.write, which does not work on Fiddle. It also has images, as it is used for captcha on the form. I'm trying to refresh the captcha image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to interrupt the click event:

```
 $("#btn_blue_refresh").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#div_captcha").replaceWith("<div id='div_captcha'><script type='text/javascript'>sjcap();</script></div>");
  });
```

Edit to respond to comment:

You probably need to break that up a bit as it's incomprehensible for mere mortals like myself! I'm not sure this syntax is perfect, but something along the lines of

```
$('#div_captcha').html('<div class="captcha_img">&nbsp;<img src="' + decodeURIComponent(imgdir) + imgid + '.jpg" width="180px" height="50px" alt="" ></div><div class="request_input"><input type="text" name="captchaBox" value="Enter Word Above" id="' + jfldid + '" name="' + jfldid + '" class="' + jfldcls + '" size="' + jfldsz + '"></div>');

$('#div_captcha').on('focus', function(){
    if(this.value=='Enter Word Above') this.value='';
});

$('#div_captcha').on('blur', function(){ 
    if(this.value==''){ this.value='Enter Word Above'; } 
    if(this.value==' '){ this.value='Enter Word Above';
});
```

Comment: Mkaatman: Thanks, but it does not work. The div content remains the same. If I remove event.preventDefault(); the div content changes, but the rest of the html is removed.

Comment: I suspect the problem is inside your sjcap() method. Can you post it?

Comment: Thanks. Just added it to the OP. :)

Comment: Can you shift it around a bit? Instead of doing the replaceWith in the click event, call sjcap and have it do the replacement. Something along these lines? http://jsfiddle.net/b102famq/

Comment: Mkaatman: Yes, that might work. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Mkaatman: Looks like I'm going to have to edit the script that changes the captcha, which is quoted above. Do you know of any way to make the document.write() part of the script write to a specific div on the page? Right now, it writes the the div where the script is located when the page loads, but if I try to call the script again, it overwrites the entire html page.

Comment: Since you're already using jQuery, instead of `document.write()` maybe just use `$("#div_captcha").html();`

Comment: Thanks, but this breaks the script.

Comment: $('#div_captcha').html("<div class=\"captcha_img\">&nbsp;<img src=\"" + decodeURIComponent(imgdir) + imgid + ".jpg\" width=\"180px\" height=\"50px\" alt=\"\" ><\/div>");
 $('#div_captcha').html("<div class='request_input'><input type=\"text\" name=\"captchaBox\"  value=\"Enter Word Above\" id=\"" + jfldid + "\" name=\"" + jfldid + "\" class=\"" + jfldcls + "\" size=\"" +  jfldsz + "\" onfocus=\"if(this.value=='Enter Word Above') this.value=''\" onblur=\"if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Word Above'; if(this.value==' ') this.value='Enter Word Above';\"><\/div>");

Comment: My response is too big, adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

as an option you can try [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) . you'll have to put the desired HTML in a external HTML file .

Heres an example :

create an external HTML file , with the desired content :

load.html

```
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis animi suscipit, repellendus enim voluptates, fuga et vero ea! Voluptas voluptatem voluptates distinctio, iste debitis beatae, autem natus aperiam aliquid similique?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae cupiditate dolorem, laborum rerum, nostrum veniam? Nobis reprehenderit, nostrum velit aliquam optio dolore ab odio minima perferendis. Ex, nesciunt reiciendis corporis.</p>
</div>
```

and then in ur main file :

```
<button id="load">Load</button>
<p id="para"></p>
```

and the Jquery to load the contents :

```
$('#load').click(function(){
                    $('#para').fadeIn( 500 , function(){
                            $(this).load('load.html');
                    }); 
                });
```

**EDIT ::** Try this excercise .

make an empty html file load.html , insert only the following content :

[link to snippet](http://chopapp.com/#qpjqowi7).

make another empty HTML file and insert only this content :

[link to snippet](http://chopapp.com/#n0bkw07s) .

See how the load function works , and then implement it in your live project .

Simple and effective .

cheers.

Comment: Alexander: Thanks, but it has the same effect. Instead of replacing the div and keeping the rest of the html page, it replaces the div and removes the rest of the html page. I want to replace the div, but keep the rest of the page.

Comment: It works fine with a snippet, but I'm trying to call the sjcap() function to replace the captcha image in the div. If I use your method, the script replaces the captcha image, but the rest of the page content is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work, but give this a try:

```
$("#btn_blue_refresh").click(function(e){
    $("#div_captcha").html("<script type='text/javascript'>sjcap();</script>");
    e.preventDefault();  //to stop the anchor tag default action
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dh9vb0x/)</kbd>

---

Does this work:

```
$("#btn_blue_refresh").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //to stop the anchor tag default action
    sjcap();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but same result. The div content changes, but the rest of the html page is removed.

Comment: If I replace the div with plain text or html, it works just fine. But if I replace it with the script to call the function, nothing happens. The function places a captcha image on the page.

Comment: @Spockrates See modified answer

Comment: Thanks, but when the onclick event calls sjcap(), it replaces the entire html content of the page instead of just the div. I don't know. I might have to put the captcha in an old-fashioned iframe, or something.

Comment: I think you've found the problem. Sounds like it's in your sjcap() function.